# how to construct regex pattern of any string if we know type of each character?

Tags: python, regex, automation

I need to construct regex pattern for any string , given we get the type of each character coded in the below format.

```
N- Numericals A- Alphabets S- Special characters.
```

I will be given an string format like - "NNNSSAAANSAA"
I need to construct a unified regex pattern for such patterns.

effort so far :

This is part of a larger problem, which was to find regex of any given string.

For which I have broken down to this solution of breaking into smaller tokens and then unifying.

Comment: You didnt try anything? Post your code, the problems doesnt seems complex

Comment: @Wonka I can find regex for each character like "/^[1-9][0-9]*$/"
But, Iam unable to merge all of them to a unified single regex.

Its harsh to downvote on my first question, it decreases the answers.

Comment: Are `éèçœÇùäû` alphabets for you? What are special characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on regex patterns found in @zb226 answer, you could construct this pattern with `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

s = 'NNNSSAAANSAA'
pattern = ''.join({'N':r'\d', 'A':r'[a-zA-Z]', 'S':r'[^a-zA-Z\d]'}[v] +  '{%s}' % len(list(g)) for v, g in groupby(s)).replace('{1}', '')
print(pattern)
```

Prints:

```
\d{3}[^a-zA-Z\d]{2}[a-zA-Z]{3}\d[^a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z]{2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you need to match characters of the following types:

- Numericals
- Alphabets
- Special characters

Regular expression engines have [(short-hand) character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html) to do that. Try:

- `[0-9]` for numericals, or its short-hand notation: `\d`
- `[A-Za-z]` for alphabets
- `[^A-Za-z0-9]` for special characters. Note the `^` which means "don't match any of the following".

Now that you know how to match the characters, we need a way to say how many of each characters we'll accept, which is done with [quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html):

- `*` means any number
- `+` means any number greater than 0 (i.e. "exists at least once")
- `{n}` means exactly `n` times
- `{n,m}` means between `n` and `m` times

So to match your example:

```
NNNSSAAANSAA
```

...you naively could use...

```
\d\d\d[^A-Za-z0-9][^A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z]\d[^A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z][A-Za-z]
```

...and shorten it using quantifiers like this:

```
\d{3}[^A-Za-z0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{3}\d[^A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z]{2}
```

**CAVEAT:** Handling the whole complexity of Unicode (think about roman numeral for example) is wee bit more difficult than that and support for such things varies wildly between regex engine implementations.

Comment: FYI: `+` means **1** or more, not greater than 1.

Comment: @Toto you're right of course, i was going a little fast there ;)